# Adding event listeners to elements which might not be on the page?

Tags: javascript

What is the best practice of adding event listeners to elements which may not appear on the page?

For example, let's say we have a comment form that appears on article pages to which a `submit` event listener is attached.

```
document.getElementById('commentform').addEventListener('submit', event => {
    /* do something */
})
```

This code is placed in a `script.js` file of the site template which is loaded on every page. However, pages on which the comment form does not appear will cause an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null...
```

How can we prevent this TypeError from occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way would be to just check to see if the element exists first...

```
const commentForm = document.getElementById('commentform');
if (commentForm) {
  commentForm.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    /* do something */
  })
}
```

In modern environments, you can use optional chaining:

```
document.getElementById('commentform')?.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    /* do something */
})
```

But an even better approach would be to have a setup such that the `commentform` on the page is *completely attached* to its associated script, so that one without the other doesn't ever come up. Often one would use a framework for this, to integrate the commentform's HTML with its submit listener. That's what I'd recommend for something professional. Lacking that, you could also put the commentform's script right next to the commentform:

```
<form id="commentform">
  ...
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById('commentform').addEventListener('submit', event => {
    /* do something */
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Notbestpractice

As @CertainPerformance says, in production code you'd want to set up your script loading so that never happens. However, one trick I've used in a userscript environment where I don't have as much control over the loading is to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    let button = document.querySelector('.blahblahblah');
    if (button) {
        button.click();
        console.log('Button found early');
    }

    // This waits to run until ".somerootelement" has changed
    let mo = new MutationObserver(function() {
        document.querySelector('.blahblahblah').click();
        console.log('Button found late');
    });
    mo.observe(document.querySelector('.somerootelement'), { childList: true });
});
```

But I would say 90% of the time this is an anti-pattern. Certainly if you can change the script loading so the dependencies load properly.

Comment: Why'd you add a "bad practice" answer when the OP clearly asked for a best practice?

Comment: Calm down, bro. I'm just tryin' to push my sweet sweet hacks.